# D3 map: zoom to group of paths

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3. What I need to do:

1. Create a map of a single state.
2. The county borders must be displayed.
3. The states regions North, South, East, West & Central must be filled with different colors. Each region is made up of counties.
4. When the user clicks a region, the map must zoom into that region.

What I have been able to achieve so far:
I have the first 3 requirements down. The problem is when I click on a county it zooms into that county instead of the region.

The code I wrote is based from the following examples:

Zoom to Bounding Box

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541

NY State with Counties Clipped

https://bl.ocks.org/gregdevs/a73f8a16f129757c037e72ecdebdd8f2

The only part of the code I created myself (and the part that I think needs to changed) is the coloring of the regions. This was done using if then else statemenents to set the following class

```
 .attr('class', function (d) {
                  if (d.id == "51105" || d.id == "51169" || d.id == "51191" || d.id == "51520" || d.id == "51077" || d.id == "51035" ||
                      d.id == "51141" || d.id == "51089" || d.id == "51143" || d.id == "51590" || d.id == "51195" || d.id == "51051" ||
                      d.id == "51027" || d.id == "51167" || d.id == "51185" || d.id == "51173" || d.id == "51021" || d.id == "51197" ||
                      d.id == "51071" || d.id == "51590" || d.id == "51155" || d.id == "51063" || d.id == "51067" || d.id == "51121" ||
                      d.id == "51161" || d.id == "51770") {
                      return "WesternRegion";
                  }
                  else if (d.id == "51083" || d.id == "51117" || d.id == "51025" || d.id == "51081" || d.id == "51037" || d.id == "51011" ||
                           d.id == "51590" || d.id == "51029" || d.id == "51049" || d.id == "51145" || d.id == "51041" || d.id == "51111" ||
                           d.id == "51147" || d.id == "51183" || d.id == "51181" || d.id == "51007" || d.id == "51135" || d.id == "51053" ||
                           d.id == "51149" || d.id == "51087" || d.id == "51760") {
                      return "SouthernRegion";
                  }
                  else if (d.id == "51175" || d.id == "51800" || d.id == "51550" || d.id == "51810" || d.id == "51710" || d.id == "51093" ||
                           d.id == "51001" || d.id == "51131") {
                      return "EasternRegion";
                  }
                  else if (d.id == "51165" || d.id == "51171" || d.id == "51069" || d.id == "51043" || d.id == "51107" || d.id == "51059" ||
                           d.id == "51013" || d.id == "51510" || d.id == "51139" || d.id == "51187" || d.id == "51157" || d.id == "51061" || d.id == "51153") {
                      return "NorthernRegion";
                  }
                  else return "CentralRegion";
              })
              ;
```

Below is the full code. In order to get it working requires downloading us.json from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json and copying it to a folder called scripts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

    .outline {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

path {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}
.background {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.feature {
  fill: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.county.active {
  fill: orange !important;
}

.WesternRegion 
{
    fill:Green;   
}

.EasternRegion 
{
    fill:Blue;   
}

.SouthernRegion 
{
    fill:#efce43;   
}
.NorthernRegion 
{
    fill:Purple;   
}

.mesh {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}  


</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var width = 960,
        height = 500;
    active = d3.select(null);

    var projection = d3.geo.albers()
        .scale(1000)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "background")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .on("click", reset);

    var g = svg.append("g")
        .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");

    d3.json("/Scripts/us.json", function (error, us) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var states = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states),
            state = states.features.filter(function (d) { return d.id === 51; })[0];

        projection.scale(1)
            .translate([0, 0]);

        var b = path.bounds(state),
            s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
            t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

        projection.scale(s)
            .translate(t);

        g.selectAll("path")
            .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
            .attr("class", "mesh")
            .attr("d", path)
            .on("click", clicked);

        g.append("path")
            .datum(state)
            .attr("class", "outline")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr('id', 'land');

        g.append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip-land")
            .append("use")
        .attr("xlink:href", "#land");

        g.selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr('countyId', function (d) {
                return d.id
                })
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-land)")
            .on("click", clicked)
            .attr('class', function (d) {
                  if (d.id == "51105" || d.id == "51169" || d.id == "51191" || d.id == "51520" || d.id == "51077" || d.id == "51035" ||
                      d.id == "51141" || d.id == "51089" || d.id == "51143" || d.id == "51590" || d.id == "51195" || d.id == "51051" ||
                      d.id == "51027" || d.id == "51167" || d.id == "51185" || d.id == "51173" || d.id == "51021" || d.id == "51197" ||
                      d.id == "51071" || d.id == "51590" || d.id == "51155" || d.id == "51063" || d.id == "51067" || d.id == "51121" ||
                      d.id == "51161" || d.id == "51770") {
                      return "WesternRegion";
                  }
                  else if (d.id == "51083" || d.id == "51117" || d.id == "51025" || d.id == "51081" || d.id == "51037" || d.id == "51011" ||
                           d.id == "51590" || d.id == "51029" || d.id == "51049" || d.id == "51145" || d.id == "51041" || d.id == "51111" ||
                           d.id == "51147" || d.id == "51183" || d.id == "51181" || d.id == "51007" || d.id == "51135" || d.id == "51053" ||
                           d.id == "51149" || d.id == "51087" || d.id == "51760") {
                      return "SouthernRegion";
                  }
                  else if (d.id == "51175" || d.id == "51800" || d.id == "51550" || d.id == "51810" || d.id == "51710" || d.id == "51093" ||
                           d.id == "51001" || d.id == "51131") {
                      return "EasternRegion";
                  }
                  else if (d.id == "51165" || d.id == "51171" || d.id == "51069" || d.id == "51043" || d.id == "51107" || d.id == "51059" ||
                           d.id == "51013" || d.id == "51510" || d.id == "51139" || d.id == "51187" || d.id == "51157" || d.id == "51061" || d.id == "51153") {
                      return "NorthernRegion";
                  }
                  else return "CentralRegion";
              })
              ;

    });

    function clicked(d) {
        //     debugger;
        if (d3.select(this).classed("NorthernRegion")) {
            alert("You selected Northern Region");
        }
        else if (d3.select(this).classed("SouthernRegion")) {
            alert("You selected Southern Region");
        }
        else if (d3.select(this).classed("EasternRegion")) {
            alert("You selected Eastern Region");
        }
        else if (d3.select(this).classed("WesternRegion")) {
            alert("You selected Western Region");
        }
        else if (d3.select(this).classed("CentralRegion")) {
            alert("You selected Central Region");
        }

        if (active.node() === this) return reset();
        active.classed("active", false);
        active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

        var bounds = path.bounds(d  ),
      dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
      scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
      translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

        g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale + "px")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");

    }

    function reset() {

        active.classed("active", false);
        active = d3.select(null);

        g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
      .attr("transform", "");
    }
</script>
```

Below is how the maps looks:
[image]

The problem is that it zooms to the county not the region:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, which seems to work pretty well.  The important changes I made were:

- Only including those counties in the state of interest (makes it run much faster)
- Indicating the "active" region rather than county
- Whenever a county is clicked, iterate through all counties in that region to get max and min boundaries for zooming (this was key)

Something weird that I noted is that, when filtering out non-applicable counties, one applicable county kept filtering out, so I manually added it back in (gross).

```
var width = 960,
height = 500,
active = "";

var projection = d3.geo.albers().scale(1000).translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
svg.append("rect").attr("class", "background").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).on("click", reset);
var g = svg.append("g").style("stroke-width", "1.5px");
d3.json("scripts/us.json", function(error, us) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var states = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states),
        state = states.features.filter(function(d) {
            return d.id === 51;
        })[0];
    projection.scale(1).translate([0, 0]);
    var b = path.bounds(state),
        s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
        t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];
    projection.scale(s).translate(t);
    g.selectAll("path").datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
        return a !== b;
    })).attr("class", "mesh").attr("d", path).on("click", clicked);
    g.append("path").datum(state).attr("class", "outline").attr("d", path).attr('id', 'land');
    g.append("clipPath").attr("id", "clip-land").append("use").attr("xlink:href", "#land");
    us.objects.counties.geometries = us.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(county) {
        return county.id >= 51000 && county.id < 52000
    });
    // Not sure why this one needs to be re-added
    us.objects.counties.geometries.push(us.objects.counties.geometries.find(function(d) {
        return d.id == 51069
    }));
    console.log(us.objects);
    g.selectAll("path").data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features).enter().append("path").attr("d", path).attr('countyId', function(d) {
        return d.id
    }).attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-land)").on("click", clicked).attr('class', function(d) {
        if (d.id == "51105" || d.id == "51169" || d.id == "51191" || d.id == "51520" || d.id == "51077" || d.id == "51035" || d.id == "51141" || d.id == "51089" || d.id == "51143" || d.id == "51590" || d.id == "51195" || d.id == "51051" || d.id == "51027" || d.id == "51167" || d.id == "51185" || d.id == "51173" || d.id == "51021" || d.id == "51197" || d.id == "51071" || d.id == "51590" || d.id == "51155" || d.id == "51063" || d.id == "51067" || d.id == "51121" || d.id == "51161" || d.id == "51770") {
            return "WesternRegion";
        } else if (d.id == "51083" || d.id == "51117" || d.id == "51025" || d.id == "51081" || d.id == "51037" || d.id == "51011" || d.id == "51590" || d.id == "51029" || d.id == "51049" || d.id == "51145" || d.id == "51041" || d.id == "51111" || d.id == "51147" || d.id == "51183" || d.id == "51181" || d.id == "51007" || d.id == "51135" || d.id == "51053" || d.id == "51149" || d.id == "51087" || d.id == "51760") {
            return "SouthernRegion";
        } else if (d.id == "51175" || d.id == "51800" || d.id == "51550" || d.id == "51810" || d.id == "51710" || d.id == "51093" || d.id == "51001" || d.id == "51131") {
            return "EasternRegion";
        } else if (d.id == "51165" || d.id == "51171" || d.id == "51069" || d.id == "51043" || d.id == "51107" || d.id == "51059" || d.id == "51013" || d.id == "51510" || d.id == "51139" || d.id == "51187" || d.id == "51157" || d.id == "51061" || d.id == "51153") {
            return "NorthernRegion";
        } else {
            return "CentralRegion";
        }
    });
});

function clicked(d) {
    var selected = d3.select(this).attr('class');
    var dxAll = [];
    var dyAll = [];
    var xAll = [];
    var yAll = [];
    // Iterate through all in class and find max values
    d3.selectAll('.' + selected).each(function(data) {
        var bounds = path.bounds(data);
        dxAll.push(bounds[1][0], bounds[0][0]);
        dyAll.push(bounds[1][1], bounds[0][1]);
        xAll.push(bounds[0][0], bounds[1][0]);
        yAll.push(bounds[0][1], bounds[1][1]);
    });
    dx = Math.max.apply(null, dxAll) - Math.min.apply(null, dxAll);
    dy = Math.max.apply(null, dyAll) - Math.min.apply(null, dyAll);
    x = (Math.max.apply(null, xAll) + Math.min.apply(null, xAll)) / 2;
    y = (Math.max.apply(null, yAll) + Math.min.apply(null, yAll)) / 2;
    if (active === selected) return reset();
    active = selected;
    scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
        translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];
    g.transition().duration(750).style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale + "px").attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}

function reset() {
    active = "";
    g.transition().duration(750).style("stroke-width", "1.5px").attr("transform", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need those big `if...else` statements. They could be hugely simplified. For instance, to get the class inside the `clicked` function:

```
var thisClass = d3.select(this).attr("class");
```

Back to your question.

An solution is getting all the paths with the class of the clicked element and pushing their bounds inside an array:

```
var allBounds = [];

var allPaths = d3.selectAll("path." + thisClass).each(function(d) {
    allBounds.push(path.bounds(d))
});
```

Then calculate the corners of all those bounds:

```
var bound0 = d3.min(allBounds, function(d) {
    return d[0][0]
});
var bound1 = d3.min(allBounds, function(d) {
    return d[0][1]
});
var bound2 = d3.max(allBounds, function(d) {
    return d[1][0]
});
var bound3 = d3.max(allBounds, function(d) {
    return d[1][1]
});

var bounds = path.bounds(d),
    dx = bound2 - bound0,
    dy = bound3 - bound1,
    x = (bound0 + bound2) / 2,
    y = (bound1 + bound3) / 2,
    scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
    translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/3e473b01de29cb7a3c0a6d8807b8b247/f6675e001dc7dcdb7ffd4c437944bb3233b417ca

PS: If you click the central region (the gray area), it **will not work**. The reason is simple: in your code, you are setting the class `centralRegion` to all paths without the given IDs in your `if...else` statement. You have to change that.

PPS: You'll have to refactor the code to set the `active` class to all the counties.

Comment: Close to my answer!  If you have any time and look at my solution, any idea why the one county keeps being filtered out?